# Perfect precision, recall and f1-score, yet bad prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, prediction

Using scikit-learn to classify a binary problem. Getting perfect `classification_report` (all 1's). Yet prediction gives `0.36`. How can it be?

I'm familiar with imbalanced labels. Yet I don't think this is the case here since `f1` and the other score columns, as well as the confusion matrix, indicate perfect score.

```
# Set aside the last 19 rows for prediction.
X1, X_Pred, y1, y_Pred = train_test_split(X, y, test_size= 19, 
                shuffle = False, random_state=None)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X1, y1, 
         test_size= 0.4, stratify = y1, random_state=11)

clcv = DecisionTreeClassifier()
scorecv = cross_val_score(clcv, X1, y1, cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=4), 
                         scoring= 'f1') # to balance precision/recall
clcv.fit(X1, y1)
y_predict = clcv.predict(X1)
cm = confusion_matrix(y1, y_predict)
cm_df = pd.DataFrame(cm, index = ['0','1'], columns = ['0','1'] )
print(cm_df)
print(classification_report( y1, y_predict ))
print('Prediction score:', clcv.score(X_Pred, y_Pred)) # unseen data
```

Output:

```
confusion:
      0   1
0  3011   0
1     0  44

              precision    recall  f1-score   support
       False       1.00      1.00      1.00      3011
        True       1.00      1.00      1.00        44

   micro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      3055
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      3055
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      3055

Prediction score: 0.36
```

Comment: Have you checked the possible imbalance?

Comment: As mentioned above, I considered it. Yet the perfect f1, recall and precision scores as well as the confusion matrix all indicate that it's not the case (as far as I understand).

Comment: `test_size= 19`  so how big is `X1` then? Also have you checked your measures against `y_test`? You could just be overfitting

Comment: Oh yes, I though y_predict was the test case, but indeed, you are never checking that x_test and y_test are good as well. So just plain simple overfitting.

Comment: @JakeH with regard to the class imbalance, if you have a really small sample it's possible you just ended up with only a single class in your set. You should actually check the class imbalance of all the different splits of your data and consider using `stratify=True` in `train_test_split`. Print out what % of your `y`s are `1` for each split (and the full set)

Comment: Also, this question probably belong on [stats.se]

Comment: @Dan, note above, I use cross validation as well as stratify to ensure that.

Comment: @JakeH you shouldn't believe anything, you should prove it to yourself. (a) It is clear from your confusion matrix that your data have a very strong class imbalance. (b) it is even more clear that you have overfit to your test set. There are plenty of resources online on how to identify and deal with overfitting.

Comment: @JakeH it's pointless to stratify your CV if you're passing in a split that wasn't stratified to begin with though... but this is all irrelevant since your principal problem here is overfitting. You need to deal with that first.

Comment: @Dan, I suggest reading the code above.. It already has stratify.

Comment: `X1, X_Pred, y1, y_Pred = train_test_split(X, y, test_size= 19, 
                shuffle = False, random_state=None)` it does not. You're using `X1` in your CV but by this point it's already not stratified. But for the fourth time, you problem is classic overfitting.

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher, Since i use CV it does that against the X1, y1 which are almost the whole dataset, except the last 19 rows for perdition.

Comment: @Dan, Note that there are two train/splits: the first is to set aside the last 19 rows for a later prediction. Everything else (X1, y1) is used for CV with the argument cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=4). In fact, the 2nd train/split is not used.

Comment: @JakeH you are training against X1, instead of X1_train as your code hints you do. You have **overfitting**. That's for sure. Make your decision tree looser.

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher - that's not correct. I actually never use X_train/y_train. 

To clarify, cross_val_score is done against the whole of features/labels. Right? So what I did is:
1. set aside the last 19 rows to be used for prediction using the first train/split line, So X1, y1 become the new X,y. while X_Pred, y_Pred are set aside for prediction.
2. cross_val_score(X1, y1)
3. predict X_Pred, y_Pred. 

I will try to limit the DT with max_leaf/etc..

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher - I took your advice and did a quick DT limit (max_depth= 5, max_leaf_nodes= 5). The scoring fell but the prediction rose. Will play/optimize with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are overfitting.

There are lots of code that is not used, so let's prune:

```
# Set aside the last 19 rows for prediction.
X1, X_Pred, y1, y_Pred = train_test_split(X, y, test_size= 19, 
                shuffle = False, random_state=None)

clcv = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clcv.fit(X1, y1)
y_predict = clcv.predict(X1)
cm = confusion_matrix(y1, y_Pred)
cm_df = pd.DataFrame(cm, index = ['0','1'], columns = ['0','1'] )
print(cm_df)
print(classification_report( y1, y_Pred ))
print('Prediction score:', clcv.score(X_Pred, y_Pred)) # unseen data
```

So clearly, there is no cross validation here, and the obvious reason for a low prediction score is the overfitting of the decision tree classifier.

Use the score from the cross validation, and you should see the issue there directly.